# Dirichlet distribution property about product

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, independence

if $\left(\tau_1,\dots,\tau_m\right) \sim Dirichlet(α1β1, . . . , α1βm)$,
where $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\beta_i = 1$, then
$(x_1τ_1, . . . , x_1τ_m, x_2, . . . , x_n) ∼ Dirichlet(α_1β_1, . . . , α_1β_m, α_2, . . . , α_n)$
I treat to go through writing the pdf of $\mathbf{\tau}$, that is:
$f(\tau_1,...,\tau_m) = \dfrac{1}{B(\alpha_1\tau_1,...,\alpha_1\tau_m)}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\tau_{i}^{\alpha_1\beta_i-1}$ but, from here idk if i can assume that $x_i$'s are iid or no bcs there doesn't tell me it